# Is there any way to reduce the execution time of random forest?

Tags: r

My dataset has 108 predictor variables. Two out of them are numeric type, rest are all binary factor variables. Whenever I run my code, the R studio stops responding.

Comment: How many rows in your data?

Comment: Welcome! Could you provide information on your dataset (number of rows as @GSW notes, and `object.size(data)`) as well as the R package you are using to run random forest (there are several). Some example code would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 108 predictor variable,SO you can apply feature selection algorithm like Boruta algorithm , Random Forest Feature Selection Algorithm e.t.c. And after apply feature selection algorithm select those variable that is most important for you .TO the help of Feature selection algorithm you can reduce your predictor variable and then your predictor variable reduce so your execution time also reduce.And you can also apply PCA for dimension Reduction purpose.That also help you tor reduce your execution time.
Please Check my given links:
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/machine-learning/feature-selection/
http://r-statistics.co/Variable-Selection-and-Importance-With-R.html
I hope that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tips on tuning Random Forest for small size in this question:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53240/practical-questions-on-tuning-random-forests